# If class exists, use these styles (SASS)

Tags: html, css, sass

I had the following in `CSS` and it was working:

```
.vc_column-inner, .wpb_wrapper, .textCard {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I need this so that multiple cards of the same block will be of equal height.

However, I only want the styles to execute if the class `customHeight` exists on the parent. So in SASS, I have the following:

```
.customHeight{
    .vc_column-inner,
    .wpb_wrapper,
    .textCard{
      height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Which is wrong since it'll just append `.customHeight` to all three divs. How would I go about this?

**Edit**:

```css
.customHeight>.vc_column-inner,
.customHeight>.wpb_wrapper,
.customHeight>.textCard {
  height: 100%;
}

.customHeight.vc_column-inner, .customHeight.wpb_wrapper, .customHeight.textCard {
  height: 100%;
}



.columnA, .columnB{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cutsomHeight">
  <div class="vc_column-inner">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">


      <div class="columnA">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="textCard">
              <p>test 1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="columnB">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="textCard">
              <p>test 2<br><br> test 1 should be same height as test 2</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will produce something like this:

```
.customHeight .vc_column-inner,
.customHeight .wpb_wrapper,
.customHeight .textCard {
  height: 100%;
}
```

if you need something like this (from what I understood):

```
.customHeight.vc_column-inner,
.customHeight.wpb_wrapper,
.customHeight.textCard {
  height: 100%;
}
```

you can use the & operator like this:

```
.customHeight{
    &.vc_column-inner,
    &.wpb_wrapper,
    &.textCard{
      height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: The output CSS looks correct. However, nothing styles show up when inspecting the element in Chrome? Either way, I added the compiled CSS into the inspect menu and it made no changes? I've created a little demo in the original question to showcase the markup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&` operator with `>` operator.

```
.customHeight{
    & > .vc_column-inner,
    & > .wpb_wrapper,
    & > .textCard{
      height: 100%;
    }
}
```

It will apply height 100% for only elements with `.vc-column-inner`, `.wpb_wrapper` and `.textCard` class which are the children of element with `.customHeight` class. [Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) about CSS selectors